# Windows Server 2008

Tags: domain-controller

explain the modifications necessary to DNS for accommodating Read only Domain Controllers. How is this different from the way DNS handles ordinary domain controllers?

Comment: Can you edit your question title as it is too vague

Answer (score 4):

All of the modifications required for accommodating a read Only Domain Controller (RODC) is handled through the `adprep /rodcprep` step, which modifies the domain schema.

Simply put, a domain-integrated zone on a RODC will not accept Dynamic Updates. A file-backed DNS zone on such a RODC would be able to accept dynamic updates, as it has a separate database from the domain database. Server 2008 allows a DC to not contain a DNS server, so putting on there is not required.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your quesiton correctly, you should only need to run `adprep /rodcprep`

RODCs are exactly what they say, *read only*. They won't write anything back to the main DCs. It will only get new data from your main DC and not write new data back to it.
Check this link out: http://itbloggen.se/cs/blogs/chrisse/archive/2009/01/25/how-read-only-domain-controllers-and-dns-works.aspx